# Can't get route params for a lazy module within a CanActivate guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an application that uses a lazy module this way:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WelcomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/items/items.module#ItemsModule'
  }
];

export const AppRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders
                      = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Within the `ItemsModule`, I would like to use a guard for one of the sub routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':slug', component: ItemComponent,
    canActivate: [ ItemFetchGuard ]
  }
];

export const coveragesRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders = 
                          RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

This guard needs to get the `slug` parameter to fetch data:

```
@Injectable()
export class CoverageFetchGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private service: ItemService,
    private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {}

  canActivate() {
    const slug = this.route.params['slug'];
    return this.service.getItem(slug)
      .map(item => {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch(itemSuccessfullyFetched(item));
        return true;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch(itemFetchFailed(error));
        return Observable.of(false);
      });
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find the `slug` parameter in the route snapshot (even in its `children` properties). It seems that this data is available later but I can't find ways to get it...

What is the approach to implement this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found out the "problem" (it wasn't actually one). I didn't use the guard the right way. We need to use the hints about the current route leveraging the parameters of the `canActivate` method instead of trying to get them from dependency injection.

Here is the way to get the parameter:

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemFetchGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const slug = this.snapshot.params['slug'];
    (...)
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UVz5YUkK0JoAy0i64Lo3?p=preview